# Monkey patch a python instance method using the original method from the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, monkeypatching

I want to monkey patch a method of a library class to define a different default for a param. This fails:

```
from functools import partial

class A(object):
    def meth(self, foo=1):
        print(foo)

A.meth = partial(A.meth, foo=2)

a = A()
a.meth()
```

with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 10, in <module>
    a.meth()
TypeError: meth() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

what is the correct way of doing this?

(Original code is using `getattr` on the method names in a loop)

The answers in the question linked involve defining a new module-level function - I would like to avoid a new function definition

Comment: Using `@override`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: replacing a function within a class of a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599045/python-replacing-a-function-within-a-class-of-a-module)

Comment: Oh I am not familiar with `@override`

Comment: Ignore my override statement, that might be my brain mixing in some Java syntax.. ouff.. That declaration might just be eye-candy-fluff. Sorry for the confusion. You should be able to just in-line replace `A.meth = new_func` and it should work.

Comment: Kind of surprises me why partial does not do the trick basically - I can always define a new function as in the question linked but would like to avoid it, out of curiosity

Comment: I think Marjtein Peiters (I'm butchering his name at the moment) and some of the more deep-divers of Python can clarify why that isn't working as you intend. I just know how to get around the problems :)

Comment: Seems to work if you instantiate `a` first and then do `a.meth = partial(a.meth, foo=1)` followed by `a.meth()`. Don't know whether that will solve your purpose

Comment: @Mortz no I want to define it before instantiating A (due to those getattr calls in different places)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Note that `A.meth` is not a simple function, it is a descriptor. Hence you need to substitute it with an object that implements the descriptor protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod):

```
In [32]: from functools import partialmethod

In [33]: A.meth = partialmethod(A.meth, foo=2)

In [34]: a = A()

In [35]: a.meth()
2
```

Comment: Oh! What is the difference between partial and partialmethod (didn't know about the latter)