# How to change part of function inside a class in python?

Tags: python, class, scikit-learn, python-decorators

I would like to change a class `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` to compute GMM with fixed means. In this [github repository](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/mixture/_gaussian_mixture.py) the function is stored, I assume it would be enough to change that `means_` will not be computed in `_m_step` function within the class `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` , but instead the values provided as initial values for means, i.e. `mean_init` parameter of the class would be used as fixed means. How to achieve this? I have tried changing it by heart by copy-paste the class and changing the part inside the function, but I can not overcome that there are dependencies which I can not load... Is it possible to change it from outside somehow?

So this is what I have tried, but I am not able to make it running:

```
import sklearn
def new_m_step(self, X, log_resp):
    sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture._m_step(self, X, log_resp)
    self.means_ = self.means_init


my_gmm = sklearn.mixture.gaussian_mixture.GaussianMixture() 
#my_gmm._m_step =  types.MethodType(new_m_step, my_gmm) # alternative which has the same error
my_gmm._m_step = new_m_step.__get__(my_gmm, sklearn.mixture.gaussian_mixture.GaussianMixture)
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'GaussianMixture' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: replacing a function within a class of a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599045/python-replacing-a-function-within-a-class-of-a-module)

Comment: I dont get how to use it in my case. I need to change part of the function within a class, not whole function.

Comment: You've read through all the answers and examples of the linked question in just 2 minutes? Maybe read them again. Hints: ``somemodule=_gaussian_mixture, testMOD=GaussianMixture, testFunc=_m_step, alternativeFunc=<whatever function you write that does what you want>``

Comment: I have seen that question before, but it did not help me, because I do not want to build that function again, just change one part. Is there any way to do it or I just have to build it again?

Comment: You can only replace the whole function, but you will not have to copy&paste the whole class. If you create a backup of the original function before you replace it, your new function could call that backup and then set ``self.means_ = <your backup value of self.means_ before you call the original function>`` after you've called the original function. That way you won't have to write a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. Do you want to write it into answer?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question once you've got it working. You can then elaborate on the steps you've taken and show the final result to help future readers. Or - if you find your own solution is not that different from the answers in the question I've linked above - you can still decide to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: I will write it down as an answer once it works, because for me it was not easy to understand how to use that code to solve my problem, might be thus useful also for someone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally solved it in this way:

```
from skleran.mixture import GaussianMixture
class My_GMM(GaussianMixture):
    def _m_step(self, X, log_resp):
        GaussianMixture._m_step(self, X, log_resp)
        self.means_ = self.means_init
```

and the original class is not overwritten within the script. If anyone has any better solution feel free to add it. If you feel the question is duplicate, vote for closing, however I did not understand from the post mentioned in comments how to add something to function inside a class, so maybe I am not alone and will leave it here.