# Outdated hashlib module in a non-current version of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, hashlib

I installed a python package that I need, and tried to import it, but there's a line of code in the package:

```
from hashlib import blake2s
```

which returned the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'blake2s'
```

After a bit of reading, I found that the hashlib module in Python 3.6+ has blake2s, but I'm using **Python 3.5.6**. Updating my Python version would solve this problem, but I don't have admin access on this system. So I'm stuck on Python 3.5.6.

Is there a way to get blake2s working in Python 3.5?

edit: I'm wondering if this can be used somehow...
https://github.com/dchest/pyblake2

Comment: you should be able to install python for yourself (not systemwide) without privilege elevation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I also need to use Python notebooks that are configured (by admins) to use the Python version installed on the server.

Comment: Depending on your situation,  you can replace member function or subclass the relevant library based on thr new code. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599045/python-replacing-a-function-within-a-class-of-a-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...
I installed the pyblake2 package (linked in my edit above), then went inside the package I was trying to install and modified the import line.

I changed
`from hashlib import blake2s`
to
`from pyblake2 import blake2s`
and then reinstalled the package with that modified line.

It worked! The package is working in Python 3.5 even though Python 3.5 hashlib does not have blake2s.