# How to change a function in python module?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, monkeypatching

I was trying to modify a function within a class. I was following the steps from this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599045/python-replacing-a-function-within-a-class-of-a-module). I want to understand why the changes are not working.

The function is:

```
def explain(self, test_df, row_index=None, row_num=None, class_id=None, bacckground_size=50, nsamples=500)
```

from  module [ktrain](https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/ktrain/tabular/predictor.py)

I am trying to get the shape values themselves instead of the plot. My changes are in

```
 def alternative_explain (self, test_df, row_index=None, row_num=None, class_id=None, background_size=50, nsamples=500)
```

Then I try:

```
import types
import ktrain
funcType = types.MethodType
predictor1 = TabularPredictor()
```

But get the error that  "name 'TabularPredictor' is not defined. Simarly, I can not make a new, inherited class from `TabularPredictor`. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I did import ktrain

Comment: Sounds like you didn't import the proper module to define `TabularPredictor`.

Comment: I  did " import ktrain"

Comment: So you need to use something like `ktrain.TabularPredictor`.

Comment: import ktrain.TabularPredictor rises error 'No module named ktrain.TabularPredictor'

Comment: No, I meant `predictor1 = ktrain.TabularPredictor()`

Comment: I tried that: module 'ktrain; has no attribute 'TabularPredictor'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're a little confused about the python `import` statement, which has several alternative syntaxes.

Using `import ktrain` will only import a reference to the module `ktrain` in your code; if you want your code to refer to anything *inside* the `ktrain` module, you need to use dot-notation, e.g. `ktrain.TabularPredictor()`. Pros: everything from the `ktrain` module is now accessible from within your code. Cons: it might be a bit wordy to type out `ktrain.TabularPredictor()` every time you want to make an instance of the class, and you might only actually *need* one or two classes from that module.

Using `from ktrain import TabularPredictor` will make the TabularPredictor class accessible in your code's namespace, so there will be no need to use the dot-notation; you can just type `TabularPredictor()` when you want to create an instance. Pros: less wordy, you only import what you need (none of the other classes or functions from `ktrain` will be accessible from within your code). Cons: you might find out later on that some of the other classes/functions in the module are useful, which means you'll have to change your import statement. It can also be a pain to have to individually import 10 different classes from the same module.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21547583/13990016).

Comment: when I do
 from ktrain import TabularPedictor
I receive an error "cannot import name "TabularPredictor" from 'ktrain' (***\ktrain\__init__.py)

Comment: I've never used the module, but, from looking at the directory structure on github, you could try `from ktrain.tabular.predictor import TabularPredictor`. The TabularPredictor class is found within the predictor.py file, found within the tabular directory, found within the ktrain package.